How to straighten the lines of a path diagram using DiagrammeR?
I am interested to use DiagrammeR  to draw a path diagram. The original codes I used generated a diagram with some curved lines. I tried to look for solutions online and I read this post DiagrammeR: Force horizontal arrows to be straight rather than diagonal. Following the suggestion on that post, I added splines = ortho, but the diagram looks messy.
Can someone please advise how can I make all the lines straight with a neat outlook?
The original codes I used:
my_graph <- grViz("digraph{rankdir = LR
                     node[shape = rectangle]  
                     A1[label = '1']
                     A2[label = '2']
                     M1[label = '3']
                     M2[label = '4']
                     M3[label = '5']
                     M4[label = '6']
                     M5[label = '7']
                     T1[label = '8']
                     T2[label = '9']
                     O1[label = '10']
                     O2[label = '11']
                     edge[color = black]
                     A1 -> M1 [label = '0.6']
                     A1 -> M2 [label = '0.6']
                     A1 -> M3 [label = '0.6']
                     A1 -> M4 [label = '0.6']
                     A1 -> M5 [label = '0.6']
                     A2 -> M1 [label = '0.6']
                     A2 -> M2 [label = '0.6']
                     A2 -> M3 [label = '0.6']
                     A2 -> M4 [label = '0.6']
                     A2 -> M5 [label = '0.6']
                     M1 -> T1 [label = '0.6']
                     M2 -> T2 [label = '0.6']
                     M3 -> T1 [label = '0.6']
                     M4 -> T1 [label = '0.6']
                     M5 -> T2 [label = '0.6']
                     T1 -> O1 [label = '0.6']
                     T1 -> O2 [label = '0.6']
                     T2 -> O1 [label = '0.6']
                     T2 -> O2 [label = '0.6']
                    }")

my_graph 


You can click here to see the path diagram generated from the codes
Same codes but added splines = ortho:
my_graph2 <- grViz("digraph{rankdir = LR
                    splines = ortho
                     node[shape = rectangle]  
                     A1[label = '1']
                     A2[label = '2']
                     M1[label = '3']
                     M2[label = '4']
                     M3[label = '5']
                     M4[label = '6']
                     M5[label = '7']
                     T1[label = '8']
                     T2[label = '9']
                     O1[label = '10']
                     O2[label = '11']
                     edge[color = black]
                     A1 -> M1 [label = '0.6']
                     A1 -> M2 [label = '0.6']
                     A1 -> M3 [label = '0.6']
                     A1 -> M4 [label = '0.6']
                     A1 -> M5 [label = '0.6']
                     A2 -> M1 [label = '0.6']
                     A2 -> M2 [label = '0.6']
                     A2 -> M3 [label = '0.6']
                     A2 -> M4 [label = '0.6']
                     A2 -> M5 [label = '0.6']
                     M1 -> T1 [label = '0.6']
                     M2 -> T2 [label = '0.6']
                     M3 -> T1 [label = '0.6']
                     M4 -> T1 [label = '0.6']
                     M5 -> T2 [label = '0.6']
                     T1 -> O1 [label = '0.6']
                     T1 -> O2 [label = '0.6']
                     T2 -> O1 [label = '0.6']
                     T2 -> O2 [label = '0.6']
                    }")

my_graph2

You can click here to see the path diagram generated by the codes
Based on @sroush codes(thank you so much for your help!), I added four paths, but two of them overlapped with each other.
The codes:
my_graph3 <- grViz("digraph{
  rankdir = LR
  splines=line  
  ranksep=2
  nodesep=1
  node[shape = rectangle]
  A1[label = '1']
  A2[label = '2']
  M1[label = '3']
  M2[label = '4']
  M3[label = '5']
  M4[label = '6']
  M5[label = '7']
  T1[label = '8']
  T2[label = '9']
  O1[label = '10']
  O2[label = '11']
  edge[color = black]
  edge [labelfloat=true] 
  A1 -> M1 [xlabel = '0.6']
  A1 -> M2 [headlabel = '0.6']
  A1 -> M3 [xlabel = '0.6']
  A1 -> M4 [xlabel = '0.6']
  A1 -> M5 [xlabel = '0.6']
  A2 -> M1 [xlabel = '0.6']
  A2 -> M2 [xlabel = '0.6']
  A2 -> M3 [xlabel = '0.6']
  A2 -> M4 [xlabel = '0.6']
  A2 -> M5 [taillabel = '0.6']
  M1 -> T1 [taillabel = '0.6']
  M2 -> T2 [taillabel = '0.6']
  M3 -> T1 [taillabel = '0.6']
  M4 -> T1 [taillabel = '0.6']
  M5 -> T2 [taillabel = '0.6']
  T1 -> O1 [headlabel = '\n0.6']
  T1 -> O2 [taillabel = '\n0.6']
  T2 -> O1 [taillabel = '0.6']
  T2 -> O2 [headlabel = '\n0.6']
  A1 -> T1 [headlabel = '0.6']
  A1 -> T2 [headlabel = '0.6']
  A2 -> T1 [taillabel = '\n0.6']
  A2 -> T2 [xlabel = '0.6']
}")

my_graph3

You can click here to see the path diagram my_graph3 generated from the codes

Please say more about "neat" and "messy" regarding this graph.  What is messiest about it?

Hi sroush, thank you for your response. I've attached the figure of the graphs in my post. You can click the link https://i.sstatic.net/AJiLR3j8.png to see the messy graph.

Still needs some work, but splines=line and a combination of labelfloat, label, xlabel, headlabel, and taillabel.  Also look at labelangle and labeldistance.
digraph {
  rankdir = LR
  splines=line  // straight lines
  ranksep=2
  nodesep=1
  node[shape = rectangle width=1.2 height=1.5]
  A1[label = "1"]
  A2[label = "2"]
  M1[label = "3"]
  M2[label = "4"]
  M3[label = "5"]
  M4[label = "6"]
  M5[label = "7"]
  T1[label = "8"]
  T2[label = "9"]
  O1[label = "10"]
  O2[label = "11"]
  
  edge[color = black]
  edge [labelfloat=true]  // more flxability
  A1 -> M1 [xlabel = "0.6"]
  A1 -> M2 [headlabel = "0.6"]
  A1 -> M3 [xlabel = "0.6"]
  A1 -> M4 [xlabel = "0.6"]
  A1 -> M5 [xlabel = "0.6"]
  A2 -> M1 [xlabel = "0.6"]
  A2 -> M2 [xlabel = "0.6"]
  A2 -> M3 [xlabel = "0.6"]
  A2 -> M4 [xlabel = "0.6"]
  A2 -> M5 [taillabel = "0.6"]
  M1 -> T1 [taillabel = "  0.6"]
  M2 -> T2 [taillabel = "  0.6"]
  M3 -> T1 [taillabel = "  0.6"]
  M4 -> T1 [taillabel = "  0.6"]
  M5 -> T2 [taillabel = "  0.6"]
  T1 -> O1 [headlabel = "\n0.6 "]
  T1 -> O2 [taillabel = "\n0.6 "]
  T2 -> O1 [taillabel = " 0.6 "]
  T2 -> O2 [headlabel = "\n0.6 "]
}

Giving:


Hi @sroush, thank you so much for taking the time to help! It's super helpful!! I greatly appreciate that. I actually wanted to add four more paths, however, two paths overlapped with each other when I added them using your codes. Would you please advise how can I separate the two paths? I've added the codes and the graph in my original post (because I can't add them here in the comment). Thank you once again!

If you can do this in the DiagrammeR environment:

set splines=true  No other changes to your input file necessary
run dot with output format = dot (this creates a text file - see https://graphviz.org/docs/outputs/canon/)
run that file through neato -n -T...  - neato will create slightly different edge locations

Giving:

